# Is a forthcoming novel always an published one?

Tags: meaning

> There was an unearthly quality to the atmosphere inside the Frieze New York art fair, like the air in a plane—still but pressurized, with an unsettling hum—when the fiction writer Ottessa Moshfegh visited to speak about her work one afternoon in May. “I hate this fair already,” she said when she walked in, handing her ticket to a very tall, very pale man dressed entirely in black lace. Almost immediately, she was lost in the labyrinth of works for sale: Takashi Murakami’s lurid blond plastic milkmaids with long legs and erect nipples; the words “any messages?” spelled out in neon tubing. It was like an enactment of the world inhabited by the protagonist of Moshfegh’s **forthcoming** novel, “My Year of Rest and Relaxation,” who works at a gallery in Chelsea, amid objects like a quarter-million-dollar “pair of toy monkeys made using human pubic hair,” with camera penises poking out from their fur. “Did I do this?” Moshfegh said, only half kidding. She sometimes gets the sense that she has the power to conjure reality through her writing.

Why is the person saying “forthcoming”?! Does it simply mean that the book was not published at that time and he or she was given a copy perhaps?

Comment: The author shows us Moshfegh speaking to herself. ("Forthcoming" means her novel is to be published soon -- it is presumably already written.) The art fair looks so much like the world in which her novel is set that she half-seriously wonders whether she created the fair herself, as if her writing called it into being.

Answer (score 3):

"Forthcoming" means that the book has not yet, but soon will be, published.  As StoneyB says, it should already have been written and accepted for publication, and the only remaining delay is in the process itself:  final edits, typesetting, printing, binding, etc.

Apparently the character's novel includes an art fair with equally outlandish artworks in it.